# Where should the image be stored for a website with spring mvc on backend and angular on frontend?

Tags: java, html, angularjs, spring

I've been trying to develop a website where people can store their profile and I am really new on this. I need to upload and display their profile pictures and other data according to their need.

I stored them in one of my locations lets say **'C:\testUpload'** and saved that location in my Database. Now I have to display that image when someone wants to view his/her profile. I tried to retrieve the data from database and store it in $scope.user as

```
$scope.user= $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("C:\\testUpload\\Screenshot (7).png");
```

And in the Html display I tried doing

```
<img ng-src = {{user}} />
```

But the Image is not displayed. It gives an error on the console

**Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/testupload/Screenshot%20(7).png**

What is my mistake in the above circumstances and what should be my solution in this case?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and some codes and links would also be very nice.

Comment: y dont u store the image it self in ur db??

Comment: That would attempt to load a file from the *user's* computer. You need to load it from the server using an URL, not a filesystem path.

Comment: If I save it in db then as the images start to increase the size of db also increases hence it will cause more problems later on @SaEChowdary

Comment: @Kayaman well the image is stored on the user's computer. Exactly on c:/testUpload. Can you help me on how to load it form the server using URL?

Comment: @BikashChapagain You can't have profile images stored on the user's computer. Even if it would show, the only one who would see it would be the user himself. Search for "image serving servlet" to see how you can create an endpoint that serves imagedata from the database or other source.

Comment: I am using apache tomcat/7.0.56 and right now i am just testing on my pc through localhost...So i saved those images on my pc... if i cannot show images from my pc then i doubt that i could show them from other sources... Any way thank you i will look into "image servind servlet" :) @Kayaman

Comment: @BikashChapagain You can show images from your PC, but you can't show them with a filesystem path. You need an URL, it doesn't matter that the image is located in `C:/testupload`, you need it to be accessible through `http://yourserver.com/testupload` or similar.

Comment: @kayaman Thank you it helped me :)